# Survey Monkey API V3

Tags: surveymonkey

I am trying to update from using the API V2 to V3 and when making calls using V3 endpoints such as https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys?api_key=xxxxxxxx&page=1 I get a 403 error:

## Developer Inactive

However the same api_key and access token work when using version 2
Do we need to take any steps through survey monkey or Mashery to update the version of the API we are using?

Answer (score 0):

An API key used for API V2 does not work for API V3. An API key for API V3 works with both versions.

If you create a new app through the [developer portal](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/) it'll automatically give you an API key for version 3. That way you can rebuild and test with a separate app without touching your original app before moving over. If you really need that same API key to work then you can contact SurveyMonkey support and they may be able to convert that API key to work with both versions.